# undefined local variable or method `post' for #<PostsController:0x007f76b8ee5be8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am getting this error but i have defined my method in the controller , i am new to ruby , what should i do help me out my error comes in the controller that @post is undefined

this is my contoller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController 

     def index
        @posts = post.all    
      end

      def show

      end

      def new

      end

      def create

      end

      def edit

      end

      def update

      end

      def destroy

      end

    end
```

this is my view

```
<h1>regular</h1>

<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<h2> <%= post.username  %></h2>
<p><%= post.description  %></p>
<% end %>
```

this is my migrate

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :username
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
  def down
    drop_table :posts
  end
end
```

this is my route

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
```

Comment: Hello, Welcome to SO. Please try to solve your self before posting here.

Comment: `post` should be `Post`

Comment: @narashima i tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use capital P.

Currently your code searches for a local variable or instance method called `post` in the controller action.

To call the class you have to use `Post`.

Comment: i cant believe this was the mistake . it worked  thanks :)

Comment: Your welcome. Would you mark this as the answer please? :)

Comment: sure i will it says after 8 mins